# ProxyPass module configuration in apache tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat

I found one documentation here to run multiple node application on single port using proxypass, I understood the concept, it just forward the request to node application port unsing ProxyPass. In that example, they used httpd, and I am using tomcat.

My question is, how can I do same configuration in tomcat?

simply I am expecting tomcat configuration for this httpd configuration.

```
ProxyPass /node http://host.xyz.com:3000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should consider using Apache httpd (or any other frontend) for this purpose. This is the software that handles the requirement best - and tomcat best serves application data.

Also, Apache httpd knows how to handle port 80 or 443, something that needs some extra work with tomcat (if you don't want to run it as root. And you actually don't want to run it as root)

It doesn't require so many extra resources, use the appropriate tool for the job. And, when you use mod_proxy, look up all the related options and understand what they're there for. You probably also want `ProxyPreserveHost On`, but I'll stop here.

Comment: I am using tomcat as application server, and nodejs as well. I want to serve both, java application and node js application using tomcat. Is there any way to do this. Internally node application is hosted on another port

Answer (score 0):

I hope the [document](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/proxy-howto.html) will be helpful.